# Calculating how long it will take for X to be within P% of C?

Tags: algorithms

I need to work out the amount of time it will take for $X$ to be within $P$% of $C$ using the following formula at $H$ hertz:
$$X = X + (C - X)\ Y$$
where $Y$ is a value between $0$ and $1$.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I have formatted your question using LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that $X$ always stays at the same side of $C$.

Initially the distance between $X$ and $C$ is $d=|C-X|$.
After the first step this distance becomes $(1-Y)d$.
After the second step this distance becomes $(1-Y)^2d$. ...

I think this should be sufficient to solve it.

Comment: The third step being $(1-Y)^3d$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.